# Show edits from Google Docs users in different colors

Tags: google-drive, collaboration

I frequently use Google Docs for collaborative assignments, and love its ability to show you where other people are typing (and who is doing it) in real time. However, when returning to a document after editing has already been done, it is sometimes difficult to see who has added what. I know it's possible to go back in the revision history, but I would like a way for *all edits* from each user to appear in a different color. So, if I edit a document, my edits would show up in one color, and *remain that color* until manually changed otherwise, and likewise with different colors for everyone else editing the document. Does anybody know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go to File - see revision history, you can see the revisions made my all the collaborators and each person has a different color

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do it automatically, but you could tell everyone to pick a color and use that color as a highlight color when they make edits.

Comment: I suppose we could do it that way, but it would be nice if there were an automated method. I know Google Docs has basic scripts of some sort now, though I don't know much of anything about them, so perhaps it could be implemented somehow through those.

Comment: As I have yet to find any better solution and it appears to be simple not possible, I'm marking this answer as accepted for now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that one way to see the authors in different colors is for everybody to be working in "Suggesting" mode (under the "Editing" button on the upper left). Eventually someone needs to accept all the suggestions if no need for different colors exists anymore, but that is very easy to do.